# fetch request in JavaScript with dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Is there is some way to do a fetch request in JavaScript with dynamic parameters?

for example:
*'''fetch (/api/$parameter1/$parameter2)'''* 

when both parameters are declared in the code above them (it determine in the previous code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use template literals, it allows you to interpolate strings with variables. (more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
let parameter1 = 'example-param1';
let parameter2 = 'example-param2';
fetch (`/api/${parameter1}/${parameter2}`)
```

Comment: You are right. Fixed.